# Java Heap Space issue in Grakn 1.6.0

Tags: python-3.x, vaticle-typedb

i have a data of 100 nodes and 165 relations to be inserted into one keyspace. My grakn image have 4 core CPU and 3 GB Memory. While i try to insert the data i am getting an error **[grpc-request-handler-4] ERROR grakn.core.server.Grakn - Uncaught exception at thread [grpc-request-handler-4] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**. It was noticed that the image used 346 % CPU and 1.46 GB RAM only. Also a finding for the issue in log was *Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1, use getErrors() for more: Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=3cb85440): io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Unable to create Channel from class class io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel)*

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Cassandra ran out of memory - currently, Grakn spawns to processes: one for Cassandra and one for Grakn server. You can increase your memory limit with the following flags (unix):

`SERVER_JAVAOPTS=-Xms1G STORAGE_JAVAOPTS=-Xms2G ./grakn server start`

this would give the server 1GB, and the storage engine (cassandra) 2gb of memory, for instance. 3 GB may be a bit on the low end once your data grows so keep these flags in mind :)